# Are there any non-mobile graphics cards that don't support "precision highp float"?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I know it is common for mobile phones to not support 'precision highp float' in fragment shaders, but are there any desktop or laptop GPUs that don't support it?  In other words, if I'm only writing my shader code for use in desktop/laptop scenarios, do I really need to do this conditional stuff recommended in the OpenGL ES 2.0 book?

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else 
precision mediump float;
#endif
```

Or can I just stick with declaring it 'highp' and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

Most Intel GPUs don't support it; so that would be most of the laptop market.  I don't know what the story is with AMD, and as far as NVIDIA cards go, GeForce 8 series and earlier won't work.