# webgl highp fragment support

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

http://webglstats.com/ seems to not have information on what percentage of devices/browsers support `highp` in the fragment shader.

Most sources report that `highp` won't work on older mobile hardware, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748355/are-there-any-non-mobile-graphics-cards-that-dont-support-precision-highp-floa) seems to indicate that most Intel GPUs (back in 2011) don't support it. I'm guessing the vast majority of hardware nowadays support it but I'm looking for some hard numbers.

Comment: you should contact the guy that runs webglstats and ask him to add that. [You can reach him here](http://codeflow.org/). I'm pretty sure my iPhone5S and my Android Nexus 5 do NOT support highp so I'm just going to guess that it's still pretty common that mobile doesn't support highp. I've never met a desktop that doesn't though and that includes old Intel GPUs that are capable of running WebGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting highp in fragment shaders is optional in OpenGL ES 2.0, mandatory in OpenGL ES 3.0, so a quick and dirty way to be sure it to check if the device support OpenGL ES 3.0. For that reason there is still a vast amount of mid-end mobile hardware out there which doesn't support OpenGL ES 3.0 and does not implement the optional highp support (Mali-300/400/450 GPUs do not support it, for example).

Pretty much all desktop hardware can support OpenGL 4.0 so tends to have highp in fragment shaders (not aware of anything vagely recent which doesn't).